# Relation between eigenvalues and a quadratic equations' discriminant

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm taking a linear algebra course and we're learning about eigenvalues.

We were given as homework to prove the known discriminant based solution(s) of a quadratic equation:

> Let $F$ be a field s.t. $char(F)\neq2$, and $a,b,c\in F$ with $a\neq 0$.
>
> Prove the known root-discriminant relation for $ax^2+bx+c=0$:
>
> - if $b^2-4ac$ isn't a square in $F$ then there are no solutions for the equation in $F$.
> - if $b^2-4ac$ is a square then the roots are: ${ \lambda  }_{ 1,2 }=\frac { -b\pm \sqrt { { b }^{ 2 }-4ac }  }{ 2a } $

Is there any real "linear algebra" based solution here?

(As opposed to doing it algebraically - starting from the known solution and working my way back to a quadratic equation)

Thanks!

Comment: Please be more specific!

Comment: @Paz Very Obscure question. Did you mean something [like this?](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_eigenvalue_problem)

Comment: @Epictetus I added the question. I hope it's clear now. Sorry!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I understand the question.

We want to formulate a quadratic equation as a linear algebra problem. Somehow we need to get a square. The simplest way to do that is to construct something of the form $v^\dagger A v$.

Imagine $v=\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ x\end{pmatrix}$. Then the quadratic equation $ax^2+bx+c=0$ is exactly

$$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & x\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} c & b/2 \\ b/2 & a\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ x\end{pmatrix}=0$$

What condition on a matrix allows this to be possible? Why is this condition *equivalent* to the existence of a solution, if the quadratic part of the equation is not trivial?

Comment: As far as I understand, a non-trivial solution is possible if the middle matrix's determinant is $\neq$ 0, which means $4ac-b^2\neq 0$. That means the kernel isn't $\{0\}$. But I can't figure out how to factor in the discriminant's sign.

Comment: Not quite. Your logic would conclude the opposite, that the discriminant must be equal to zero. However the problem has $v^\dagger$ on the left too. Consider an eigenvector decomposition of $v$.

Comment: I've just started learning about eigenstuff not too long ago. You meant finding the eigenvectors of the middle matrix and decomposing $v$ according to them?

Comment: Yes, but you don't need to actually do any computations. What does the (sign of the) determinant tell you about the eigenvalues, in general? Start with that. Now imagine you transformed to a basis where the matrix is diagonal and looked for solutions to $v^\dagger A v$.

Comment: What does the sign of the determinant tell me about the eigenvalues? I only came up with this: Let's say we have two eigenvalues, then the sign is positive iff the two have the same sign.

Comment: Yep! Now imagine you are looking at the possible values $v^\dagger \begin{pmatrix}\lambda & 0 \\ 0 & \mu\end{pmatrix}v$ can take. When could it possibly be zero if $v\neq 0$?

Comment: I think I got it: it's possible when $\lambda \mu <0$ (as a result of $-\lambda=\mu x^2$). So they can't have the same sign which means the determinant must be negative and the discriminant must be positive.

Comment: But actually, now I'm not quite sure I understand why the matrix I'm looking for is diagonalizable (as you said before, the equivalence to a non-trivial solution).

Comment: Yes! The reason is that *real symmetric matrices are diagonalizable by orthogonal transformations* (a spectral theorem) but you can simplify the argument somewhat if you prefer. If you want to explicitly construct the solutions, of course, just go ahead and solve for the eigenvectors, and see the quadratic formula appear when you write $v$ as a sum of the eigenvectors. That way it's explicit, no quoting of theorems.